# React doesn´t rerender ComponentDidUpdate after react-select Input changed state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am really lost on this one:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class selectDemo extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: "",
    data: [{ Model: "Option1" }, { Model: "Option2" }]
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.selectedOption.Model)
    );
  };

  renderButton = () => {
    return (
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        {this.state.selectedOption.Model}
      </button>
    );
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.selectedOption !== prevState.selectedOption) {
      this.renderButton();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const value = selectedOption && selectedOption.Model;
    return (
      <div>
        <div name="selectedOption" className="section">
          <Select
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Select Option"
            name="selectedOption"
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            labelKey="Model"
            valueKey="Model"
            optionClassName="dropdown-item"
            options={this.state.data}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">{this.renderButton}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default selectDemo;
```

All I want to achieve is that after I made a Selection from a dropDown List created with the react-select package a button gets rendered on the page. Everything is working fine except for the fact that the button does not get rendered when a selection has been made. Anyone has an idea where I am wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I checked that and the handleChange function does get called since I am using an error function, so no need for constructor and binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call renderButton explicitly `this.renderButton()`

here is the right way :

```
class SelectDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: "",
    data: [{ Model: "Option1" }, { Model: "Option2" }]
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.selectedOption.Model)
    );
  };

  renderButton = () => {
    return (
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
        {this.state.selectedOption.Model}
      </button>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const value = selectedOption && selectedOption.Model;
    return (
      <div>
        <div name="selectedOption" className="section">
          <Select
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Select Option"
            name="selectedOption"
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            labelKey="Model"
            valueKey="Model"
            optionClassName="dropdown-item"
            options={this.state.data}
          />
        </div>
        {this.state.selectedOption && <div className="form-group">{this.renderButton}</div>}
        <div className="form-group">{this.renderButton()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I am trying to achieve, I tried this as well earlier, but this causes the button already to initally render even before a selection has been made. But it should only render after a selection has been made (Could as well exchange the button with some text and this would then also show up before a selection was made

Comment: I had `this.state.selectedOption && `in the render method and i simply remove the `componentDidUpdate` one

Comment: or you can put this on the first line of your `renderButton` function `if(!this.state.selectedOption) { return null }`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function call to your `this.renderButton` in your main `render` function. It should look like:

```
<div className="form-group">{this.renderButton()}</div>
```

Also, in your `componentDidUpdate`, you are calling `this.renderButton()` but that will not cause it to render the returned markup. The state update from your `handleChange` will trigger the re-render of your component without you needing to check in `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks, but please see my comment above to @Jayffe reply. But your point in regards to the unnecessary componentDidUpdate function is valid.

Comment: You can add some conditional logic around the `this.renderButton()` call. Something like `{this.state.selectedOption && this.renderButton()}`